# Pattern printing with odd count of stars

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

How to print this pattern? I have done regular patterns but I am unable to get odd stars.

[image]

Comment: This is like: first line: 2 spaces 1 star. Second line: 1 space 3 stars, third line: 0 spaces 5 Stars and backwards for line 4 and 5. This is the idea

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple list comprehension:

```
n = 5
print("\n".join((a := [("* "*i).center(n*2 + 1) for i in range(1, n + 1) if i&1]) + a[::-1][1:]))

     *
   * * *
 * * * * *
   * * *
     *
```

You can change n to anything you want